# Chart not loading data on page load

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I have implemented some charts on my view to show stats, but it don't load correctly, only after reloading the page 2, 3, 4 or 5 times...

First, i make a ajax call to get data, and then i use the result do load and create chart.js chart.

```
<script>
    var bSt = [];
    var lSt = [];
    var cSt = [];
    var mainStatsChart = {};
    var horizontalBarChartData = {};
    var percentChart = {};
    var color = Chart.helpers.color;

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetStats", "Toons")',
        data: { id: @Model.ToonID },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            bSt = data.baseStats;
            lSt = data.legStats;
            cSt = data.criticalStats;
            CreateData(bSt, lSt, cSt);
        }});

    function CreateData(baseStats, maxLevelStats, criticalStats)
    {
        mainStatsChart = {
            labels: ['Strenght', 'Agility', 'Stamina', 'Intelligence'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Base Stats',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.purple,
                data: [
                    baseStats[0],
                    baseStats[1],
                    baseStats[2],
                    baseStats[3]
                ]
            }, {
                label: 'Level 70 Gear 11 Stats',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
                data: [
                    maxLevelStats[0],
                    maxLevelStats[1],
                    maxLevelStats[2],
                    maxLevelStats[3]
                ]
            }]

        };

        percentChart = {
            labels: ['Critical Chance %', 'Critical Value %'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Base %',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.purple,
                data: [
                    criticalStats[0],
                    criticalStats[1]
                ]
            }, {
                label: 'Level 70 Gear 11 %',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
                data: [
                    criticalStats[2],
                    criticalStats[3],
                ]
            }]

        };
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('chStats').getContext('2d');
        window.chartOne = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: mainStatsChart,
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: false
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

        var ctx2 = document.getElementById('chPercent').getContext('2d');
        window.charTwo = new Chart(ctx2, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: percentChart,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: false,
                    text: 'Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart'
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

But it don't work properly, the chart shows up without data, only the chart design load.

EDIT: Data returned from Controller

```
            int[] baseStats = { stats.Strength.Value, stats.Agility.Value, stats.Stamina.Value, stats.Intelligence.Value };
            int[] legStats = { stats.Strength70.Value, stats.Agility70.Value, stats.Stamina70.Value, stats.Intelligence70.Value };
            int[] criticalStats = { stats.CriticalChance.Value, stats.CriticalChance70.Value, stats.CriticalValue.Value, stats.CriticalValue70.Value };

            return Json(new { baseStats, legStats, criticalStats, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
```

Comment: Are you sure that the data are actually passed into the CreateData function?

Comment: It looks like you're creating the charts before you have your data.

Comment: @Bonfire Yes, i've added the controller method.

Comment: @David But i call the method to create data only after getting it from post call

Comment: @Bazz: AJAX is asynchronous.  You need to use the data in the response to that call, not in code invoked after you begin that call.  You're *creating* the data in your variables correctly, but you're *using* the data before it's created.  Put `console.log` statements in your AJAX success handler and in your `window.onload` handler to check the order they're running.